# Protractor error 105 when trying to run spec.js

Tags: protractor

my protractor was working fine and when updated it it couldnt open a simple spec file it always gives thsi error. I searched for a solution but couldnt find one the conf and spec files are samples from the protractor site itself im pasting the error below hope you could help. Thanks in advance

conf.js error

```
[09:10:06] E/configParser - error code: 105
[09:10:06] E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file spec.js

C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130

throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configurat
ion file ' + filename);
            ^
Error
    at ConfigError.ProtractorError (C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:10:22)
    at new ConfigError (C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:26:16)
    at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130:19)
    at Object.initFn [as init] (C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:94:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:130:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

The conf and spec files are the sample ones from the site

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you post your config (edit the question and include it there)? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the post im replying in case you didnt check

Comment: you can open up `C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130` and in the `catch` you can put `logger.error(e)`
example:
`catch (e) {
  logger.error(e);
  throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename);
}`
should print out something like `E/configParser - { [Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }`

Comment: The error is saying that it cannot load the file with a module with config. This is working as designed. The error message: `E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file spec.
js` should be helpful to figure out what's going on. 1. It is a configuration error, 2. It could not load the file. And someone pointed out (below) that you were loading the spec file instead of a configuration file.

Comment: I  explained that i loaded the conf file and it gave that error but now is working fine and im running multiple e2e tests on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per @jtzero's remark, the issue lies with the configuration parser masking the actual error message when loading the configuration file.

Depending on whether you run Protractor as global or from the folder, open up (`C:\Users\y\AppData\Roaming\npm\`)`node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js` at line 13‌​0.
There you can add `logger.error(e);` e.g:

```
    /**
     * Public function specialized towards merging in a file's config
     *
     * @public
     * @param {String} filename
     */
    ConfigParser.prototype.addFileConfig = function (filename) {
        if (!filename) {
            return this;
        }
        var filePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), filename);
        var fileConfig;
        try {
            fileConfig = require(filePath).config;
        }
        catch (e) {
            logger.error(e);
            throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename);
        }
        if (!fileConfig) {
            throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'configuration file ' + filename + ' did not export a config object');
        }
        fileConfig.configDir = path.dirname(filePath);
        this.addConfig_(fileConfig, fileConfig.configDir);
        return this;
    };
```

This will then report the error in the output. In my case it was a failing call to `require()`:

```
[10:36:29] E/configParser - { [Error: Cannot find module 'phantomjs'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Repored GitHub issue #3301: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3301

**Update**
Protractor 4.0 will include a fix for this problem to report the masked error message with a stack trace.

Comment: Editing the file as you suggested didn't change the log output for me, but it did give me an idea.  I opened up `node` and tried to `require()` the conf file in the REPL and got the error I was looking for.  I was missing a node module.

Comment: @JoeSkeen Maybe it didn't work because Protractor runs either global or local, and you have to edit the correct one depending on how protractor is executed.

Comment: @BartVerkoeijen Thx, This hint saved me a LOT of debugging time. I'm still confused, if I should like this "extensibility" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You should be running the conf.js file, not the spec.js file.

It looks like you are running the command "protractor spec.js" when it should be "protractor conf.js". The error says it is looking for a configuration file but you are passing it a spec file.

Comment: When i start up the conf.js it does the same error il edit it in the post above the changed one

Comment: Did you run "npm install" in the folder you have those files?

Comment: yeah i did npm -g install protractor i even reinstalled node and did it all over again always the same error

Answer (score 2):

Passing correct path to conf.js file can be a solution. Try to navigate to folder, in which you have this file and then launch the command again.

Of course, point at conf.js file, not spec.

Comment: yeah i did all that it didnt work somehow i reinsalled everything and it works now so il mark this as solved tnx for the help.Have no idea what was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling no idea how or what was the problem

Comment: To the downvoters: How is it not the solution when in my particular case it fixed the problem and it ran smoothly after i reinstalled node, protractor and selenium webdriver. I dont know what you expect me to do or do you want me to come up with a made up solution well @Ddave 'this doesn't solve the problem... this is not the solution.' feel free to add a solution since you know that wasnt the solution

Comment: It should be pointed out that he DID indeed solve the problem. Just because this isn't the solution to the problem you were hoping for doesn't mean they didn't solve their problem by doing this. To suggest otherwise is flat out incorrect. Just because my car has issues, doesn't mean I can't sell it to get rid of my problem with having a car that has issues, it just means the car's issues didn't go away. Developer are people, remember that they were looking for a solution, to things not working, they weren't looking for 'a way it can be fixed without reinstalling'.

Comment: 'Reinstall the app' or 'Restart the computer' is never an answer a programmer would be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (with another error code), and fixed adding the java path to the environment variables (SDK installer did'nt configure it automatically).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because the content of the `conf.js` is not valid.
I have wrongly used `seleniumAddress= "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"` instead of `seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"` (using equal `=` instead of colon `:`).

> (Error 105 - Issue with the conf.js)

After changing the `conf.js` it's working fine,

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
specs: ['spec.js'],
capabilities:{'browserName': 'chrome'},
onPrepare(){ 
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
},
onComplete(){
},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue . But it might be because we have not saved the file in visual studio whatever code we have written we have to save the file. I have saved it and then ran it and it worked fine for me. For me this was the solution. Whatever code we have written we have to save it before running it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you sure you are answering the question? The user is talking regarding Protactor in top of Angular and you are answering regarding Visual Studio...

Comment: yes because i was using protractor only in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    capabilities:{'browserName': 'chrome'},
    onPrepare(){ 
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    },
    onComplete(){
    },
};
```

However make sure that webdriver-manager is updated or started or driver connection might be refused.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be in the correct path, where conf.js is then run `protractor conf.js`

Answer (score 0):

The same issue i faced and i used as below to resolve.

exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['spec.js']
};